# Windows not getting an ULA address from my DHCP server

Tags: networking, dhcp, ipv6

I have `isc-dhcp-server` running on my local RasPi. I have the following configuration:

```
ddns-update-style none;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
log-facility local7;
authoritative;

option dhcp6.name-servers fc00::1;

subnet6 fc00::/7{
        range6 fc00::10 fc00::50;
}
```

All my devices get an IPV6 address from there, except my Windows client. It refuses to accept an address from that range. Is there any way to force it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple: I had forgotten that IPV6 needs Router Advertisements to give other clients IP addresses. `isc-dhcp-server` does not offer that. So I had to install `radvd` via apt and add the following config:

```
 1 interface eth0
 2 {
 3         AdvSendAdvert on;
 4         AdvManagedFlag on;
 5         prefix fc00::/7
 6         {
 7         };
 8 };
```

I also had to uncomment `net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1` in the kernel via `/etc/systemctl.conf` and enable it via `1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1`. Then Windows accepted a `fc00::` address. Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: Strictly speaking, IPv6 only needs Router Advertisements to give the default gateway address; DHCPv6 _can_ assign lease-based host addresses as an alternative to RA. If Windows doesn't use DHCPv6 for address assignment, that's another issue. (But at least it _supports_ DHCPv6-based address assignment... many devices, such as Android, indeed require RA prefix advertisement.)

Comment: @grawity Actually, my Android 8 phone accepted the IP adress without the RA and the Managed Flag.